# Conditional styling of a table based on a drop-down

Tags: jquery, css, forms

So, I have two objects:

1. A table with a number of rows and columns. One of these columns is called "Builder"
2. A dropdown containing all the possible "Builders" that could be in the table

What I want to do is have conditional CSS such that when you select "Builder X" in the dropdown, all **rows** containing "Builder X" are hilighted.

My initial plan was to dynamically give each row a class based on its builder (which I've done), and then modify the CSS when you change the option in a dropdown (which I can't figure out how to do properly).

Here's a (borderline useless) Fiddle that shows the situation I'm in: http://jsfiddle.net/convoke/bTM6D/8/

Conversely, if there's a smarter/better way to do this, I'm open to hear it.

Comment: At the time of page render, would it be possible to add a class to each table row (not just the column) of the specific builder?

Comment: @jaredhoyt If I'm understanding you correctly, yes. The values in each cell (builder and otherwise) are coming from variables.  So, I define each row as having class=$buildervariable, as well as $buildervariable being the actual CONTENT of the builder column in that row.

Comment: Durrr. I get what you were asking now. I didn't set my fiddle up accurately. You're right, the whole row should have had the "builderx" class, not just the cell.

Comment: No worries, Lokase got you set up. However, if the number of builders isn't exorbitant, there's an alternative solution of adding the builder name to the table class when the drop-down is updated, and using multiple CSS rules to highlight the rows. Something along the lines of: `$('table').attr('class', builder);` then `table.builder-1 tr.builder-1 td, table.builder-2 tr.builder-2 td { /* highlight CSS */ }` The only real benefit of this though would be to minimize jQuery traversing.

Comment: The number of builders is dyanmic (powered by custom fields in a WP backend)... practically, it's a small number. But, I have no idea what the client will do with it once I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jsFiddle, should start you out:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bchgu/

Comment: This looks like an excellent start! All the heavy lifting is taken care of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would normally use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript framework to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#idOfDropDown').change(function(){

        // Remove existing active classes from the table
        $('#idOfTable tr').removeClass('active');

        // Add the new active class to the appropriate builders
        var builder = $(this).val();
        $('#idOfTable tr.' + builder).addClass('active');

    });

});
```

What the above code does is when you choose an option from the drop down list of builders, it takes the value field of the selected option and finds all elements with that class on the page, it then adds the 'active' class to those elements which you could then highlight using CSS.

This relies on the value of each builder in your drop down list being the same as the class name on the builder within the table.

Comment: This would not remove the class active on previously selected builders when the drop-down is changed multiple times.

Comment: This still wouldn't function properly, but it's close. First, you're removing the class `active` from the table, not the specific row (fix with `$('#idOfTable li.active').removeClass('active');`). Second, I'd suggest adding a little more specificity to the row selector (e.g. `$('#idOfTable li').filter('.' + builder).addClass('active');`)

Answer (score 1):

you could use a data- attribute on each row to denote its builder:

```
<tr data-builder="x"> ... </tr>
```

then you could do the following in your drop-down change event

```
$("#my_table").
    find("tr").removeClass("highlighted").
    find("tr[data-builder='" + selectedBuilder + "']").addClass("highlighted")
```